# Stop PayPal from setting up automatic payments

Tags: paypal

Often when I want to pay a bill using PayPal it automatically sets up future payments which I rarely want to do. Here is what the payment screen looks like (some personal information has been whited out):

[image]

As you can see a the bottom it says "Use PayPal for future payments to XXX". There seems to be no way out of this. I have to explicitly go to a specific screen which involves multiple button pushes and then "Cancel" my "preapproved payment". As a result of this insanity I have dozens "cancelled" subscriptions in my "preapproved payments" list.

Is there any way to stop PayPal from doing this? I want to pay the vendor ONCE only. How do I do this and prevent a "preapproved subscription" from being set up?

Comment: Find another vendor; this one very clearly wants to sell you a subscription service rather than a one time purchase and if that isn't what you want you shouldn't be doing business with them.

Comment: I just realized you also asked the question I just suggested as a dup. How is this question any different?

Comment: @TTT It isn't. I completely forgot I asked the question 3 weeks ago. I just got another bill, so it annoyed me again and I forgot I asked the last time it happened. Sorry about that.